# Is physical tape backup better than disk to ensure integrity

Tags: backup

When assessing tape backups vs online disc backups, which of them ensures better protection from integrity incidents?

For example, if the system is compromised by an attacker or virus or malware and I know the date when it happened, I can roll back data backup from tape before that incident and it will be fine. In online and disc backup solution, I can not be so sure because the backups also can be harmed as they are available from the same systems where the malware, virus etc lives.

So what do you think about tape vs disc? Particularly in financial institutions.

Comment: There are good comparison available on the internet you can read "http://www.eversyncsolutions.com/disk-vs-tape.html"

Comment: This question is not about "choosing between tape and disk", it's about "should backups be accessible/modifiable from production?".  As a sysadmin, I'd like to say that if your backups can be modified by a production system while they are in storage, they are not backups.  You might call them that, but they are not.

Comment: Ladadadada, how do you ensure that online, disc backups are not modified? For example, VMWare machine backups or SQL dumps?

Comment: In my case, the backup system connects to the client systems to perform the backups.  The client systems have no way to connect to the backup system.  I also store alternating backups on separate filesystems.  You could remount the filesystem as read-only after each backup too.  These measures were designed to prevent *accidental* deletion and not protect against *malicious* modification however they do certainly make the latter somewhat more difficult.  Storing hashes of the backup files offline would *detect* violations of integrity.

Comment: @jam If you have a SAN, you're likely to be able to physically separate your backup server from your production network - it gets access to the storage fabric, but nothing else. Essentially this works as if you're backing up, bit for bit, a disk that your operating system doesn't recognise - it is highly unlikely you can mount a successful exploit that way.

Comment: Time based cryptographic hash?

Comment: Note that there is a growing availability of "immutable" online backup options which solves the integrity issue.

Comment: @schroeder Yes there are. There's also the option of using services like AWS Quantum Ledger to detect unapproved changes to data. However, I genuinely feel like archival or immutable backups are only part of the issue; there's a fundamental question here about whether detective or preventive controls are needed, especially if we're talking about PCI DSS processes or other business-critical data. Those questions are slightly outside the OP's scope, though, which is why it seems like a bit of an X/Y issue to me if we were to do a "five why's" analysis.

Answer (score 5):

These days it doesn't actually make a huge difference. Or rather, it depends very strongly on your backup plan, disaster recovery plan, your [RPO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_point_objective) and [RTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_time_objective) and the scenarios you expect to want to recover from.

In any modern environment; you're likely to also have some sort of SAN. Your backup solution should interact with the SAN, but *not* the rest of the network; this allows you to back up data without exposing your backup solution to risks associated with the hosts you're backing up (this is a generalisation).

The decision between disk and tape should come down to your environment and your requirements. If you need to store your data for a long time: tape, properly handled can last decades, so as long as you test their integrity every ~10 years, you should be pretty safe. It is cheaper per GB (in the order of something like 90%), and the principles behind storage and retrieval are well understood. It is however, very, very slow compared to disks.

Disk can potentially be always available, it is a ***lot*** faster and lends itself to replication via WAN/etc. - but you generally have to leave them on and running to verify their integrity, and buying more disks can be a limiting factor if you're keeping your data for a good amount of time (how many fit in your array?).

In most environments, you have a combination of disk and tape; certainly for environments with any sort of compliance overhead. Disk backups deal with replication and hot site DR, tape deals with historic backups and long term storage.

To answer the question:

> Is physical tape backup better than disk to ensure integrity?

It depends on how long you're storing, your backup cycle, and what you're backing up *for* (will you need the data in a hurry?).

> So what do you think about tape vs disc? Particulary in financial institutions.

I think any serious environment will likely have both. Particularly financial institutions that require high availability and minimum downtime - if their server room floods, you'd expect them to be up at Site B very quickly (so, from disk), and if they need to dig up accounts from 30 years ago, I'd expect them to be able to by going to their tape library.

Answer (score 2):

It truly depends heavily on your specific and current capabilities. You need to ask yourself the following questions:

1. What are our current capabilities? That is, what infrastructure currently exists, do you have an enterprise SAN, do you have a tape library, a tape robot, what does your current backup solution support?
2. What are your retention requirements? Are you subject to any regulations or legislation that require you keep backups for a length of time?

Some things to keep in mind about the two formats.

1. Disk is faster and cheaper.
2. Tape has a longer proven track record for storage.
3. Disk often requires fewer components, in that it is black-boxed into the SAN.
4. Tape will require, at minimum, physical tapes, robot, and storage facility.
5. Tape expertise is aging out. Kids these days aren't as familiar with it.

The question of which ensures higher integrity is really hard to answer since it depends entirely on what time frame you're interested in. Maintaining integrity over 7 years is a very different ball of wax than 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Bob put together a very good summary, however I think it's important to note that newer tape (LTO5 and LTO6 and beyond) are working to close the gap in speed due to LTFS (Linear Tape File System).  Some good reads:  https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/tape_data_storage/case_studies/pdf/WhitePaper_LTFS-TakesTapeToNextLevel.pdf and http://www.spectralogic.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=members.docContactInfoForm&DocID=3427

Answer (score -1):

### TL;DR

> When assessing tape backups vs online disc backups, which of them ensure better protection from integrity incidents[?]

This is a bit of a false dichotomy. Spinning media, solid state drives, optical media, and tape all have different use cases, price points, and trade-offs. From a data integrity standpoint, it depends a lot on what you mean by "integrity" and what trade-offs you're willing to make.

As with all things security, you have to define your threat model and understand the trade-offs between controls. Your question is *not* as simple as "which is better" because all types of media are better at different aspects of maintaining integrity.

### Media Integrity

Modern tape, when properly stored, has an archival life of 30 years or more. In contrast, unpowered HDD media has an average lifespan of about 7 years. Consider this archival lifespan infographic from OWC:

[image: Comparison of Media Lifespans]

Note that M-DISC optical media is not covered here. It's an outlier that is theoretically good for a thousand years of archival storage if you don't scratch it or leave it on your car's dashboard, but the format is severely limited by its current maximum capacity of 100GB per disk, which is likely insufficient in comparison to other options.

In addition to having a limited shelf life, actively-used HDD or SSD drives are also more likely to fail during continuous use, and can be harder to take offline than optical or tape media. In addition, optical and tape can be purchased in more tamper-resistant forms, such as non-rewritable optical disks or WORM tapes. While you can certainly apply integrity monitoring tools like Tripwire to HDD or SSD media, that's a detective control rather than a preventive one.

### Data Integrity

No matter what media type you use, if you write bad data to the media, you have lost integrity. So, data integrity controls need to cover a lot more ground than just choosing media types.

Controls like referential integrity in a database, checksums of critical files and data archives, and other tools need to be considered. While all media will allow you to implement parity and validation checks with the right software, it's generally built into tape systems at the hardware or software level. As an example, the proprietary BRU format for archiving to tape currently checksums every 2KB of data, and is relatively quick to verify. On the other hand, you can use [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) or [dvdisaster](https://dvdisaster.jcea.es/) to add parity data to a tarball or DVD, which might allow you to recover data in spite of media aging or scratches on optical disks. Then again, you could add parity data to files you're writing to tape, too.

Tape is *designed* for backups and archiving, and the LTO standard is *almost* keeping pace with the growing size of modern disk drives. LTO-9 was a deliberate exception to the doubling of capacity, and was held back for compatibility reasons, but the roadmap for LTO is intended to keep pace with the continuing growth of hard drive sizes over the next couple of generations.

### Cost and Portability

Generally, tape *hardware* is often the most expensive, but in volume the cost per terabyte is much lower than any of the other options. In addition, a set of modern LTO-9 tapes (which hold 18TB native without compression) is going to be a lot more portable than other options. Moving large quantities of offline data off-site on tape will require fewer disks, NVMe cards, or M-DISCs, and a lot lighter and less fragile than shipping hard disks or SSD carriers around.

Media that is cost-prohibitive to ship safely, or more likely to get damaged in the transportation process, is inherently more at risk for data and media integrity issues. If you're shipping exabytes or petabytes of data around, tape is pretty much the only way to go.

### Restoring Data

Tape is getting faster, but it's always going to be slower than HDD or SSD, especially for random access. [LTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape_File_System) brings a reasonably performant approximation of random access to LTO tape, but for a full restore swapping HDD drives or streaming data from SSD is going to be faster than linear tape. Again, though, tape is *designed* for doing incremental and differential backups, so it's going to at least be competitive in many (but certainly not all) recovery scenarios.

Ultimately, you have to look at your business continuity plans and acceptable mean time to recovery to determine which types of media are going to serve you best. HDD or SDD will back up and restore faster, but are likely to cost more and fail more often. These are trade-offs you'll need to consider; there's no single solution that will be ideal for all use cases, which is why many companies use a mix of software solutions, RAID hardware, multiple availability zones, warm and cold fail-over sites, and archival data options to solve the problems of media and data integrity that you're raising.

Comment: The OP explained the type of integrity they were asking about and their threat model.

Comment: @schroeder Not clearly. Viruses and malware are vectors; they aren't *directly* the source of data integrity problems, nor the only source of integrity problems in general. They are certainly a *system* integrity problem, but as someone who does a lot of work with large financial institutions this is absolutely not the limit of what "integrity" should mean. I chose to take a broader view of the issue of integrity as one of the CIA pillars, and provided trade-offs related to the various solutions so the OP can select the controls and backup media that suit the full situation rather than an X/Y.

Comment: But even with the *vectors* you can count out integrity issues such as media integrity. So, I'm not sure that you are answering what was asked. You appear to be answering  the title and not the body of the question.